# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n!}$ using squeeze theorem.

Tags: calculus, limits

I am assigned to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n!}$, but for my course's level of knowledge, we must use the squeeze theorem.

I can easily find the right side of the theorem (a limit that is bigger than the given one) by using the arithmetic mean and geometric mean inequality
$\sqrt[n]{n!}=\sqrt[n]{n(n-1)\dots1}<\frac{n+(n-1)+\dots+1}n=\frac{n(\frac{1+n}2)}n=\frac{1+n}2,$ and we know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1+n}2=\infty$.

Can you help me find a sequence that is smaller than $\sqrt[n]{n!}$ but has the limit to $\infty$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: You could find a lower bound on n! in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575389/factorial-lower-bound-n-ge-left-frac-n2-right-frac-n2)

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Thank you for stating the question clearly and showing your work. To make progress, consider case where $n = 2k$ is even  and use the estimate $n! \ge n(n-1)(n-2) \dots  (k+1) \ge \left( \frac{n}{2}\right)^{n/2}$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes thank you very much I appriciate u

Comment: @OmG If this is for a calculus class (which I assume by the tags), then Stirling seems a little overpowered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\lim\limits_{n \to{+}\infty}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$ is infinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136626/lim-limits-n-to-infty-sqrtnn-is-infinite)

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$n!\cdot n! = (1\cdot 2 \cdot \cdots \
\cdot (n-1)\cdot n)(1\cdot 2\cdot \cdots \cdot (n-1)\cdot n)=\left( (1\cdot n)(2\cdot (n-1))\cdots ((n-1)\cdot 2)(n\cdot 1) \right).$

For each $k=1, 2, \cdots, n$,

$k\cdot (n-(k-1))-n=nk-k^2+k-n=n(k-1)-k(k-1)=(n-k)(k-1)\geq 0$

which implies that $k\cdot (n-(k-1))\geq n$.

Thus,

$(n!)^2\geq n^n \implies (n!)^{1/n}\geq \sqrt{n}$

Does this help?

Answer (score -2):

Hint: You can use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):

$
\sqrt{2 \pi n}\ \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n e^{\frac{1}{12n + 1}} < n! < \sqrt{2 \pi n}\ \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n e^{\frac{1}{12n}}.
$

Comment: That's the standard approach, but it's not elementary.

Comment: @Yooo it is. It shows a lower and upper bound on $n!$ and consequently on $\sqrt[n]{n!}$ as well.

Comment: I see this answer almost everywhere and i really appriciate u for it, but I am looking for a more natural solution ,just to kinda develop a problem solving mentality when it comes to limits